# how to transform a rdd to array except using collect because collect operation costs too much time?

Tags: apache-spark

collect may cost too much time,
so i want an operation which can save time .
my rdd just have an  array which is very small ,if using collect,it is expensive.
and the type of rdd is RDD[Int,(Array[Array[Double]])],the length of rdd is just 1.so who can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a very low quality question. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what you have tried so far!

Comment: If your RDD is very small. There is no need to use and RDD but rather a simple collection

Answer (score 0):

If the length is just 1 then why not try `rdd.first`

Comment: collect will collect every partition, first will not. Collect on a single partition will be fast. Why are you using an RDD to hold a single record anyway?

Comment: because a use rdd.combineByKey ,and the result is rdd which contains a single record, so i want to change the rdd into array and i use rdd.collect yesterday ,it stll cost much time ,so any other way?

Comment: Collect probably took so long because it is the first action in you're code. The combineByKey is not executed until the collect, making it seem like it is the collect taking so long.

Comment: yeah,thank you.And  now i have a lot of data to process on cluster,and the type of processing result is RDD[Array[Double]] ,i finally i want to collect(or reduce ) them as Array[Double](average Array[Double]),which operation can i use to save time?i use aggregate or reduce ,but it cost too much time.

Comment: Use a reduce to create the Array[Double]. If its taking a long time you will need to look at tuning the cluster configuration. A good place to look is the [Spark Tuning Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html), the cloudera website is also worth a look.